# Incorrect Magic Mouse battery status

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, macbook-pro, magic-mouse

I'm running 14.04 LTS on a MacBookPro1,1. I'm running `blueman 1.23-git201403102151-1ubuntu1`, and though my Magic Mouse is working fine, my system seems to think that its battery level is 0%. How can I get my system to show the correct battery level for my Magic Mouse?